# Schedule the meeting in/on the remaining slots

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which of these is better? 'In' or 'on'?

> "Schedule the meeting **in** the remaining slots."

"Schedule the meeting **on** the remaining slots."

I want to express that only a certain number of slots are left, and I wish to schedule a meeting ___ one of those.

Thanks.

Comment: You normally put something in a slot or slots, for most senses of slot, including a timeslot. But I don't think anyone would object to "on" in this context, as you put a meeting on a schedule, on a calendar, on a plan, etc. So either?

Comment: The first blank needs to be filled with 'for/on one of', not just a preposition.

Comment: timeslots are drawings on a page. timeslots are filled in. "Schedule the meeting using one of the remaining timeslots".

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the English.Stackexchange!

As @Edward points out, here are some scenarios to consider. Others may pitch in if needs be.

If you are the person scheduling the meeting, or if you know someone is doing it, you would say,
The meeting/a meeting will be scheduled on next Friday at ...

If you are informing/confirming to someone about an already scheduled meeting, you would say,
A meeting/the meeting is already on schedule or is scheduled for next Friday.

You may also say,
The n slots are available for scheduling a meeting/the meeting on Friday.

To the first blank, it would be appropriate to say,
Schedule the meeting in one of the remaining slots.

You see, rather than the preposition, it is also about the expression in the context. Don't overthink. Noone can fine you for being on schedule!!!

Comment: Thank you; it makes things a lot clearer now. Also, in normal usage, is 'for' usually preferred over 'on'? For example - The meeting will be scheduled on/for Friday.

Comment: @SarthakKrishna as pointed out above, the choice comes down to the context. Though linguistics are part of language learning, the usage of a language is not just about rules and repertoire. It's much more about the context, the culture, the suitability and it's an expression for and between people...

Comment: Yes, schedule the meeting **in** one of the remaining slots.